# Javascript window.onload or document.ready doesn't work in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, window, onload

I want to run an event on the loading of the page... I can't use body onload... because I have many others events.

So I `try a lot of solutions... :

**Work for Firefox but not in chrome :**

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", adminArboOuvrirEvt, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("load", adminArboOuvrirEvt);}
```

or

```
$(window).bind('load', function(){
   adminArboOuvrirEvt();
})
```

**Doesn't work nor in Firefox nor in Chrome :**

```
$(function(){
    adminArboOuvrirEvt();
});

$(window).ready(function(){
     adminArboOuvrirEvt();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     adminArboOuvrirEvt();
});
```

My others events are :

```
window.onload = function(){ height("menu1","menu2"); };
window.onresize = function(){height("menu1","menu2"); };
```

Thanks in advance !

**Edit : I noticed that on google chrome it works once ! but if I refresh does not work anymore. If i come from an external website and come back, work once... 
Is there a event cleaner or ... ?**

Comment: Of course it usually works. Do you have jQuery working ? Did you try to debug ?

Comment: Yes Jquery is working, I use others plugins using Jquery like Jstree...

Comment: Probably you have a problem with `bind` - http://api.jquery.com/bind/ Try `on` Bind is used is used in Javascript 1.8.5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind